# Computing a feasible exchange bijection between bases of a matroid

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics

A [base-orderable matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base-orderable_matroid) is a matroid in which, for any two bases $A$ and $B$, there exists a *feasible exchange bijection*, that is, a bijection $f: A\to B$ such that, for all $a\in A$, both $A-a+f(a)$ and $B-f(a)+a$ are bases.

Given two bases of a base-orderable matroid, is it possible to compute a feasible exchange bijection in polynomial time?

All papers I found on this topic just consider the existence of such a bijection, but not its computation.

Comment: Doesn't this solve it? Build a bipartite graph on vertex set $A \cup B$. Put an edge $(a,b)$ iff A-a+b and B-b+a are both bases. Find a perfect matching.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow you are right.. I did not think hard enough.